# Localstorage getitem and setitem JavaScript to TypeScript conversion

Tags: typescript

Can someone please help me in converting the below code from JavaScript to TypeScript?

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('testUi').service('localStorage', localStorage);

    localStorage.$inject = ['$window']

    function localStorage ($window) {
        var storage;
        if ($window.localStorage) {
            storage = $window.localStorage;
        } else {
            storage = {
                items:[],
                getItem: function(key) {
                    return this.items[key];
                },  
                setItem: function(key,value) {
                    this.items[key] = value;
                }
            };
        }

        //exports
        this.get = function (key) {
            return storage.getItem(key);
        };

        this.set = function(key,value) {
            storage.setItem(key,value);
        };
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note. JavaScript *is* TypeScript ([see *why TypeScript*](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html)). So that code should compile as is in a ts file.

That said if you *want* to convert it to a class you can:

```
class LocalStorage {

    static $inject = ['$window'];
    constructor($window) {
        if ($window.localStorage) {
            this.storage = $window.localStorage;
        } else {
            this.storage = {
                items: [],
                getItem: function (key) {
                    return this.items[key];
                },
                setItem: function (key, value) {
                    this.items[key] = value;
                }
            };
        }
    }

    storage: any;

    get(key) {
        return this.storage.getItem(key);
    }

    set(key, value) {
        this.storage.setItem(key, value);
    }
}

angular.module('testUi')
    .service('localStorage', LocalStorage);
```

This gives you the advantage of having a *documented* public contract for the service.

## More

I have public / free forever video on the subject : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yis8m3BdnEM

Comment: Thanks a lot Basart .

Comment: I am getting the below mentioned errors app/js/components/localstorage/local-storage-service.ts(12,21): error TS7006: Parameter '$window' implicitly has an 'any' type.
 app/js/components/localstorage/local-storage-service.ts(18,40): error TS7006: Parameter 'key' implicitly has an 'any' type> app/js/components/localstorage/local-storage-service.ts(21,45): error TS7006: Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.