# cant access localStorage in angular 2

Tags: angular, local-storage

i have a project generated with angular cli. 
i used auth0 for the authentication but i get an error saying that local storage cannot be found in 
auth.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

// Avoid name not found warnings
let Auth0Lock: any = require('auth0-lock').default;

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  // Configure Auth0
  lock = new Auth0Lock('vo2lImwjnYPMKIpnRmV95Cmqt8nBfkfk', 'zied.eu.auth0.com', {});

  constructor(public router: Router) {
  
    // Add callback for lock `authenticated` event
    this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult) => {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    });
  }

  public login() {
    // Call the show method to display the widget.
    this.lock.show();
  }

  public authenticated() {
    // Check if there's an unexpired JWT
    // This searches for an item in localStorage with key == 'id_token'
    return tokenNotExpired('id_token');
  }

  public logout() {
    // Remove token from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
  }
}
```

**strong text**
localStorage is a default keyword 
shall i import localStorage ? but from where ? 
also it s not only localStorage i get the same error when using **window**

Comment: Looks like a duplicate and has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36054111/4712391

Comment: Your link is about angularjs and this is Angular2+